# Autolayout scrollview with collectionview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have been struggling with this for a few days now, and I am looking to see if someone can help me with this AutoLayout problem.

In my iOS7 application, I have a `UIView` that has a `UIScrollView` and inside it a `UIView`(container) with some elements positioned. I have in there, a `UIImageView`, `UITableView`,  `UICollectionView`, `UITextView` and a `MapView`. There is no height constraint on the `UIScrollView` and the container `UIView`. There are no height constraints on the `UICollectionView` and the `UITextView`.

What I want to accomplish is

1. The `UITextview` should expand to the content size as in all the text should appear without any vertical scrolling enabled for the `UITextView`.
2. The `UICollectionView` should always show all items and there should not be any scrolling enabled there as well.

Overall, I want a `UIScrollView` with items in it, that scale based on content. I have tried numerous things, but failed. 
If anyone has pointers or suggestions on how to go about doing this, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. so I solved this problem by creating a IBOutlet for my NSLayoutConstraint on the UITextView in question.

I simply computed the height and then applied it on the constraint and it worked..

@Fogmeister - Your solution will also work, but it would require me to rewire a whole UI page.. Your approach is definitely a feasible one and shall keep in mind for future iOS apps..

Answer (score 1):

OK, I would go about this in a completely different way.

First, get rid of the scrollView completely.

Just use a UICollectionView for this entire interface.

The UICollectionView can take a UIView for a section header. Make this UIView with your UITextView inside. You will need to manually calculate the correct height for your UITextView (and UIView).

Something like...

```
CGSize size = [theText sizeWithFont:<the font used> constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

Then just populate your collection view.

By doing this your collection view will control all the scrolling. Because you have set the textview to the correct size in the header you will have all the text there.

Comment: I understand what you are saying..basically use the header and footer of the UICollectionView to render any other UI elements I want so that the superview in this case is actually a stylized collection view.. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if you want stuff to move with your collection view content then just put it into the header and footer. That way you don't have to estimate the size of the collection view. You just put it on your screen and the collection view will sort the rest.

Comment: that is a very neat idea.. I will try this out.. I want to add a UIImageView, small tableview and a textview in the header and a mapview in the footer of the collection view..and based on what you have mentioned, as long as the content size is computed correctly, everything should render..

Comment: Hmmm... it sounds like a very complex view. It started as just a UITextView and UICollectionView. What is the entire view showing? Is there a way you can separate the tableView into another screen. You have very limited space to put a text view, collection view, table view and image view into one screen on an iPhone.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not very descriptive of my problem.. I am going to list the views I need to render in order of how they must appear vertically.. UIImageView, UITableview,UICollectionView,UITextView,MapView.... among these UICollectionView and UITextView need to expand based on content size.. I am ok with the view scrolling..but can't change the layout.. as the design is already agreed upon..

Comment: OK, I'd do this a different way then. Use a UITableView as your "super view". Possibly with sections. The first section will have the UIImageView in a cell. The second section will be the contents of your table view cells. The third section will be a single cell with a UICollectionView in it (you'll need to have a delegate and datasource for it), the fourth section a cell with a text view, the fifth section a map view, the sixth a text view again. You can then calculate the heights required and set the height on the relevant cells.

Comment: Hmm.. I was hoping there is a better answer than using UITableView..but you are correct... that does seem to be clean way of getting this done..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45935/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-sharath)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

I assume your issue is with the height of the views, that affect the scrolling.

In the `textViewDidChange:` I would set the frame of the `UITextView` same as it's `contentSize`. When they are both the same, scrolling gets disabled.

After populating your `UITableView` and calling `reloadData`, I would set it's frame same as it's `contentSize`.

The mapView (`MKMapView`, I suppose) has the same frame throughout, I suppose. So you just use it's fixed height. If it changes height, you must store it's changing height each time it changes.

Once you have all the heights, add them up, and set the frame of the outer view same as then combined height of the inner view. Iterate this to all nested views, beginning from innermost views, and moving to outer views.

The catch here is, every time your content changes, the frames have to be resized. Hence changing the frames in `textViewDidChange:`, after `reloadData`, etc makes sense.

**EDIT** : One thing you might want to do first is, getting rid of redundant views. Your view hierarchy seems Rube Goldberg to me. The lesser views you have, the lesser work you will have to do.